# Excel VBA "formula" function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with the Excel VBA Formula function. I want my VBA sub to generate the following formula in a cell:

```
=VLOOKUP(C5;data!J6:K611;2;TRUE)
```

Therefor, I used the following VBA line:

```
Sheets("test").Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C5;data!J6:K611;2;TRUE)"
```

This results in an error: "Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error"

If I use the following statement and afterwards manually add the "=" in front of the formula, the functions works well:

```
Sheets("test").Cells(1, 1).Value = "VLOOKUP(C5;data!J6:K611;2;TRUE)"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In principle, that should work fine. To get more insight, enter the formula manually into the spreadsheet, and investigate the value of the property `Formula` in the immediate window. Maybe you can spot the difference then.

Answer (score 4):

I think the conversion of delimiters takes place in the spreadsheet rather than in VBA - where you require `,` rather than `;`.

Please try:

```
Sheets("test").Cells(1, 1) = "=VLOOKUP(C5,data!J6:K611,2,1)"
```

Comment: This indeed solved the issue. So in general, in VBA all arguments of a function should be separated by commas. Only when the function is placed inside an Excel cell using VBA, these commas are converted by Excel to ";". Is this correct?